# Программное перемещение метки в коллекции

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть следующий неработающий код:

```
let object = objectManager.objects.getById(id)

if (object) {
   console.log(object.properties)
   console.log(object.geometry)
   console.log(object.options)

   object.geometry.setCoordinates([latitude, longitude])
}
```

Выбрасывает ошибку несмотря на найденный объект с геометрией

```
{type: "Point", coordinates: [55.7458, 37.6273]}
[Error] object.geometry.setCoordinates is not a function. (In 'object.geometry.setCoordinates([latitude, longitude])', 'object.geometry.setCoordinates' is undefined)
```

Похоже что возвращается не GeoObject а просто структура, если так выходит в коллекции невозможно программно передвинуть метку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В object manager вы не можете передвинуть существующую метку. Просто удалите её и добавьте заново с новым id и новыми координатами.

Если хотите передвигать метки с помощью setCoordinates используйте обычные метки.